# Why is there a paragraph tag in my github README.md?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Here is the markdown in my README.md file:

```
1. Item Number 1
2. Item Number 2
3. Item Number 3
4. Item Number 4
5. Item Number 5
6. Item Number 6
```

Which produces this result:

1. Item Number 1
2. Item Number 2
3. Item Number 3
4. Item Number 4
5. Item Number 5
6. Item Number 6

This happens in a few other lists as well. I looked at the source code using Chrome and there are two peculiar things going on: the fifth item is straight up just missing and the sixth item has a paragraph tag in it (see below). If I look at Item number 5 by using the inspect element option in Chrome, it's there in the code along with the nested paragraph.

```
<ol>
<li>Item number 1</li>
<li>Item number 2</li>
<li>Item number 3</li>
<li>Item number 4</li>
<li><p>Item number 6</p></li>
</ol
```

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue in some public repository or Gist?

Comment: The readme is public.

Comment: You probably have an invisible character in your markdown file... Open it up with something like SublimeText (or any text editor) and show hidden characters.

Comment: No dice. I just dumped the markdown. This is a minor issue not worth more than the time I've committed to it (pun intended) and I've found an acceptable workaround anyway.

Comment: If this question is not worth your time, why waste ours? Delete the question if you don't care about it anymore.

Comment: Someone else might want the answer if one is ever posted. And if I ever figure it out, I'll answer it. The reason I posted in the first place was because I didn't find an answer here at SO despite searching around for a while.

Comment: @DrewRush, if this is a public repository, can you share a link?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to edit directly the `REAMDE.md` with the inline editor, provided by the GitHub website itself.

The list the editor generates doesn't suffer from that bug.